# dynamodb atomic increase for not-yet-present key in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a newbie for nodejs.
I have a very simple DynamoDB table called `IdCount` with string primary key, `id`(string).

I want to use the atomic increase shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html) but including nonexistent key as well.

Note that I used `count` field (`N`: number).

My code is:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function increaseIdCounter(id) {
    var table = "IdCount";

    var params = {
        TableName:table,
        Key:{
            "id": id
        },
        UpdateExpression: "Set count = if_not_exists(count, :zero) + :increase",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":increase": { "N": "1"},
            ":zero": { "N": "0"}
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    var res = ddb.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("failed to update ", id);
        } else {
            console.log("Returned new value: ", data.Attributes.count);
        }
    });
    return res;
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var re = await increaseIdCounter(event);
    
    const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(re.Attributes.count),
            };
    return response;
};
```

From this code, from AWS lambda console, I got:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:33:52)"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion will be greatly helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you do a `console.log(data)` inside the anonymous function in `ddb.update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.update(params, [callback])` returns an `AWS.Request`, not a Promise. To get a Promise, you need to call `AWS.Request.promise()`.

It's pretty unconventional to supply a callback and await a Promise. I would suggest not supplying the callback since it is optional and you aren't really doing anything meaningful in it. Your code would be something like this:

`return ddb.update(params).promise()`

Comment: Thank you very much, @tleef !!! Your solution removed this error. Also, I needed to change the field name from `count` to something else because it is a reserved term. I got  an error on the updateExpression line:`Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: +, operand type: M"`.  But I will search the solution separately from this for clean Q&A. Thank you again.

Comment: I found the last error solution. Needed to change `":increase": { "N": "1"},  ":zero": { "N": "0"}` to `":increase": 1, ":zero": 0`